# Unable to move unallocated space to root partition using gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, root, unallocated

I have checked the other threads but it still doesnt solve my problem. currently, the partition looks like this:

[image]

where the my main root is `/dev/sd5` and the unallocated space is to the right of it .

I have moved the swap files to the most right as well.

But when I try to resize the root folder, there is no option for me to add the unallocated to the root which is `/dev/sd5`. :(

[image]

Comment: Increase the size of the extended partition `sdb2` first, then you will be able to increase the size of `sdb5`.

Comment: thx. it worked!

Comment: @mook765 Please work out your comment into an answer: it constitutes a valid answer to this question.

Comment: @djack, if mook765 turns his comment into an answer, then please mark it as the accepted anwer for the benefit of future users of the site

Comment: yea @vanadium. there was no option to mark his comment as an answer.